# Set different viewport width for different devices with client code?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

I'm making a responsive site with three states (full, 480px and 320px).

Scaling to device-width look good on smartphones and devices with screen smaller than 700px, which is where the first responsive mode kicks in.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`

However, on the iPad i want the width to be 1200px so the page initially shows zoomed out in it's "full glory".

Is there any way to make this by client side code? I know i could fetch user agent on server side but since i am not making the back end code, i'd prefer a html/js solution.

Of course, a responsive state for iPad's would be ideal, but there's not time or money for that and the desktop site works good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will be the solution for anyone else coming here, but what solved this to me was setting `min-width` to each responsive states `<body>`.. made the site load decent enough on the ipad..